# Redirect while moving item from wishlist to cart

Tags: cart, wishlist

I need to change the default action after adding item to cart from wishlist. By default when you hit "Add to basket" button you will be redirected to the cart. I want user to be redirected back to wishlist.

I also know that going to *Admin > System > Configuration > Default Config > Sales > Checkout > Shopping Cart > “After adding a product redirect to shopping cart”: Yes or No* fixes my problem but I want to be able to do this only for wishlist and not globally, for one store only!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write an observer listen to the post_dispatch event

```
'controller_action_postdispatch_wishlist_index_cart'
```

and change the response to a redirect to the wishlist.

So create a new module/extension and add the following to your `config.xml`:

```
<global>
    ...
    <events>
        ...
        <controller_action_postdispatch_wishlist_index_cart>
            <observers>
                <yourcompany_yourmodule>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>YourCompany_YourModule_Model_Observer</class>
                    <method>controllerActionPostdispatchWishlistIndexCart</method>
                </yourcompany_yourmodule>
            </observers>
        </controller_action_postdispatch_wishlist_index_cart>
    </events>
</global>
```

Then in your `Observer.php` add the following method:

```
public function controllerActionPostdispatchWishlistIndexCart()
{
    Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getResponse()->setRedirect(Mage::app()->getRequest()->getServer('HTTP_REFERER'));
}
```

That's it. Every time you will try to add something from your wishlist to your cart you will be redirected back to wishlist.

Comment: "a bit more detailed instructions." @Tim aahh yes :-) Thanks!