# checkout_cart_add_product_complete not fired. Bug or feature?

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, cart, event-observer, bug, wishlist

While trying to answer [this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/1021/redirect-while-moving-item-from-wishlist-to-cart) question I ran into a strange behavior.

The `checkout_cart_add_product_complete` event is working nice while adding a product to cart from a catalog. However if I try to move product to cart from a wishlist the event doesn't fire.

The reason for it `Mage_Wishlist_IndexController::cartAction()` is adding product to cart through `Mage_Checkout_Model_Cart::addProduct()` method and not through cart controller (where `checkout_cart_add_product_complete` is firing).

So the question is if it was made intentionally or is it a bug?

Comment: Is there an issue with observing `checkout_cart_product_add_after` event instead? It's *just* upstream.

Comment: @benmarks: sure, but `checkout_cart_add_product_complete` is much more tasty as it already has `request` instance inside :-)

Comment: I see. Still, the request object is just a quick `Mage::app()->getRequest()` call away, same as it was retrieved by Front Controller. I think you and I prefer to not tie observers to request if it's not already done. :-)

Comment: @benmarks: (more upstream) `checkout_cart_product_add_after` was not suitable with the mentioned question as redirect was required there. The solution was using `postDispatch`.

Comment: Where would we be without those full action name events?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Judging from this comment in `CartController.php`:

```
/**
 * @todo remove wishlist observer processAddToCart
 */
```

This it definitely a legacy bug.